# TypeScript type for all derived interfaces

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I have an interface inheritence hierarchy like this:

```
interface IBase { type: stirng; }
interface IDerived1 extends IBase { type: "Derived1"; }
interface IDerived2 extends IBase { type: "Derived2"; }
...
```

These are actually generated interfaces for C# types, that's why the `type` discriminator property on them.

Is it possible to wirte a type in TypeScript for all the possible `type` string literal values,
based on the existing type hierarchy only,
so without specifying them manually one by one?

I would like to get smg like this:

```
type AllTypesOf<T extends {type: string}> = /* ? what comes here ? */;

...

const myVar: AllTypesOf<IBase>; // "Derived1" | "Derived2" | ...
```

Which I'd use like this:

```
function mySwitch(myArg: IBase) {
    const type = myArg.type as AllTypesOf<IBase> // "Derived1" | "Derived2" | ...
    switch(type) {
        case "Derived1":
        case "Derived2":
            // ok

        case "Derived3":
            // NOK, error, does not exist such
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript follows basic inheritance rules: parents don't know anything about their children. You could make an Enum of all the values, and then reference them in your types:

```
enum AllTypesOf {
  DERIVED_1 = "Derived1",
  DERIVED_2 = "Derived2"
}

interface IBase { type: AllTypesOf }

interface IDerived1 extends IBase { type: AllTypesOf.DERIVED_1 }

function mySwitch(myArg: IBase) {
    const type = myArg.type // Automatically typed as AllTypesOf
    switch(type) {
        case AllTypesOf.DERIVED_1:
        case AllTypesOf.DERIVED_2:
            // ok

        case AllTypesOf.DERIVED_3: // error, does not exist in enum
            // NOK, error, does not exist such
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would need to specify the enum members one by one. That I want to avoid, because  these interfaces are generated from C# classes - whenever one writes a new C# class, one had to manually extend the enum as well. The point is to find a solution without this manual extra work.

Answer (score 2):

For this a union type alias would make a lot of sense.
For example, with the types you specified in your question such a union type alias could look like this:

```js
// Your types
interface IBase { type: stirng; }
interface IDerived1 extends IBase { type: "Derived1"; }
interface IDerived2 extends IBase { type: "Derived2"; }
// The new alias:
type ICombined = IDerived1 | IDerived2;
```

This new type `ICombined` can then be used as you intended. To get for instance a type entirely made up of the strings that are possibilities for the `type` field, you can write `ICombined["type"]`.
With the switch statement as an example, the type inference works as well, and trying to use a string that isn't an option for the `type` field results in a

> Type '"some string"' is not comparable to type '"Derived1" | "Derived2"'

compiler error.

Comment: Thanks, but I would need to specify the union type "members" one by one. That I want to avoid, because  these interfaces are generated from C# classes - whenever one writes a new C# class, one had to manually extend the union type as well. The point is to find a solution without this manual extra work.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, to my knowledge, that's not possible. Though I'd also add, if all of these are generated, it surely should be a possibility to generate the union type as well, right? Maybe not out of the box with an existing tool, but it shouldn't be too hard to do via command line

Comment: If it is not possible with pure TypeScript typing, we will go with the code generation approach. But it was worth asking. Thank you for the answer and tip

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done in pure Typescript, and probably never will. Typescript is designed to (mostly) compile modules in isolation from one another; it only looks at other modules when you import them or configure it to look at them via tsconfig. To do what you want, it would have to go hunting through **all** other modules, just in case they import this interface and define an extension of it. Typescript doesn’t offer that.

Comment: These generated interfaces are written into a global script file, not into a module file - they are not isolated modules

Comment: @nvirth Doesn’t matter—there’s no way for Typescript to _know that_. As far as it cares, `IBase` is available for extension by anyone who wants to—and it will never know everyone who wants to. There’s also no way to treat “everything from this module” as a type, that I can tell—even with an explicit, named module, trying results in errors saying it can’t be used as a type.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Thank you very much!